# Method for word determination within UITextView.text and modifying word with prefix using Swift 2.2, iOS 9.3 & Xcode 7?

Tags: ios, swift, swift2, uitextview, nstextstorage

Using a TextView for user message entry it is editable and selectable during user editing.
One of the buttons below the field, toggles the TextView between editing and hash-tagging mode.
When toggled to tag, the TextView has it's editable & selectable properties disabled, and I have a function to detect taps and returns the character position within the text.

I need to determine the word, if any, tapped on, and modify the word in the UITextView.text by prefixing it with a # unless it already has two hashes it which case it removes the hashes.
I'm using regular expressions for the logic.

I have not been able to find a high level method for determining the word of the character tapped on.
I have searched through the Apple's Dev. Lib. and sites like raywenderlich and Grok Swift, but cannot find the method I am sure must be there.

I could implement by testing if the current charcter is a valid word divider if not then decrement character index and test until the word boundary is determined.  At which point, I return to the prior index and test for the # character, in the case it is a #, I would test the next character and in the case it is not a #, I would add the # character to the start of the word.

Is there a function within UIKit, TextKit, or a method of UITextView or NSTextStorage, that will return the word of the character tapped and NSRange of that word?
Also what would be the correct method for adding the # to the TextView's text?
[textView:shouldChangeTextInRange:replacementText or textView.textStorage:replaceCharactersInRange:withString:]

I have worked commercially on PC, PlayStation and GameBoy, but this is the first time developing an app and using the iPhone/Mac platform, so I could really use advice.

Answer (score 0):

for detecting the # you need to call the code inside the delegate shouldChangeCharactersInRange

```
    let stringprocess = stringfordetecting.text
     let tok =  stringprocess!.componentsSeparatedByString(" ")
    for item in tok

    {
        let demo = String(item)

        if demo.hasPrefix("#") 
        {

        let range = (stringfordetecting.text! as NSString).rangeOfString(item)

        //add code

        }

        else
        {
         //add code    
        }
```

for detecting the tapped character index add a guesture to the textview

```
let tapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "textTapped:")
    tapGesture.headline = indexPath
    tapGesture.numberOfTapsRequired = 1
    textview2.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture)


func textTapped(recognizer: MyTapGestureRecognizer){

    let textView: UITextView = recognizer.view as! UITextView
    var layoutManager: NSLayoutManager = textView.layoutManager
    var location: CGPoint = recognizer.locationInView(textView)
    let position: CGPoint = CGPointMake(location.x, location.y)
    location.x -= textview2.textContainerInset.left
    location.y -= textview2.textContainerInset.top
    var charIndex: Int
    charIndex = layoutManager.characterIndexForPoint(location, inTextContainer: textview2.textContainer, fractionOfDistanceBetweenInsertionPoints: nil)

    if charIndex < textview2.textStorage.length
            {

        print(charIndex)
            }
```

}

Answer (score 0):

for detecting the tapped character in a textview inside the tapguesture recogniser function

```
 func textTapped(recognizer: MyTapGestureRecognizer){

    let textView: UITextView = recognizer.view as! UITextView



    var layoutManager: NSLayoutManager = textView.layoutManager
    var location: CGPoint = recognizer.locationInView(textView)


    let position: CGPoint = CGPointMake(location.x, location.y)

location.x -= cell.messageLabel.textContainerInset.left
    location.y -= cell.messageLabel.textContainerInset.top

    var charIndex: Int
    charIndex = layoutManager.characterIndexForPoint(location, inTextContainer: cell.messageLabel.textContainer, fractionOfDistanceBetweenInsertionPoints: nil)

    if charIndex < cell.messageLabel.textStorage.length {


        let stringprocess = textview.text


        let tok =  stringprocess.componentsSeparatedByString(" ")

       // let attributedString1 = NSMutableAttributedString(string:stringcheck as String)

        for item in tok

        {
            let demo = String(item)

            if demo.hasPrefix("@") {

                let range = (stringcheck as NSString).rangeOfString(item)



                var i = range.location
                while i <= range.location+range.length

                {
                    if i == charIndex

                    {
                        print(demo)

                }

                    i++

                }




            }



         }
        }
```